# Как узнать код станции по ее названию? Яндекс.Расписание API

Tags: javascript, html, яндекс-расписания

Не подскажите как узнать код станции по ее названию?

Я, например, беру название станций "Москва" - "Киров" из input:text
А в запрос AJAX нужен именно код станции, как его узнать?

Вот формат (по коду станции у меня все работает)

```
https://api.rasp.yandex.net/v1.0/search/ ?
  apikey=<ключ> 
& format=<формат>
& from=<код станции отправления>
& to=<код станции прибытия>
& lang=<язык>
& [date=<дата>]
& [transport_types=<тип транспорта>]
& [system=<текущая система кодирования>]
& [page=<страница>]
```

Вот "FROM" и "TO" это код-станции, а не названия городов!
Как узнать код-станции по его(города) названию?

Заранее благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

Судя по документации, яндекс полагается на стороннюю классификацию

https://tech.yandex.ru/rasp/doc/reference/schedule-point-point-docpage/

https://tech.yandex.ru/rasp/doc/concepts/coding-system-docpage/

Answer (score 0):

В апи яндекс расписания действительно нет метода, возвращающего список станций с кодами по текстовому запросу. Веб-версия черпает подсказки с ресурса:

```
https://suggests.rasp.yandex.net/all_suggests?format=old&part=<city>
```

Передав в `part` запрос можно получить код, сокращенное и полное название потенциальных станций.